# Inform parent component of children's connection status

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating an app which is in React and Electron. I am trying to make a component which opens three TCP sockets and renders children when they are all connected. It roughly looks as follows (simplified):

```
export class Device extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    port: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    host: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };
  render() {
    const { port, host, children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="device-mount">
        <TCPSocket name="commands" port={port} host={host} />
        <TCPSocket name="messages" port={port} host={host} />
        <TCPSocket name="routines" port={port} host={host} />
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The TCP sockets will dispatch the `CONNECT_ATTEMPT` event on `componentDidMount`, `CONNECTED` when successfully connected, and `DISCONNECTED` when closed.

I have found an "unclean" solution by simply making a connect event that will use a single component and fire all the events itself and then binds a `.then` handler after they are all connected. However this does not seem very good practice, as it is not modularizable.

My goal is to inform the parent component when all of these `TCPSocket` components have fired their `CONNECTED` event. The first thing that comes to mind is [child context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), but effectively, I want that in the reverse direction.

How can you inform a parent component about multiple child components status?

Answer (score 2):

Give each a callback that he'll invoke with it's name and status:

```
export class Device extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    port: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    host: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);

      this.getTCPSocketStatus = this.getTCPSocketStatus.bind(this);
  }

  getTCPSocketStatus(name, status) {
      // whatever you want to do with the status
  }
  render() {
    const { port, host, children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="device-mount">
        <TCPSocket name="commands" port={port} host={host} notifyStatus={ getTCPSocketStatus } />
        <TCPSocket name="messages" port={port} host={host} notifyStatus={ getTCPSocketStatus } />
        <TCPSocket name="routines" port={port} host={host} notifyStatus={ getTCPSocketStatus } />
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Each child should then use the callback, for example:

```
class TCPSocket extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { notifyStatus, name } = this.props;
        this.props.notifyStatus(name, 'CONNECT_ATTEMPT');
    }

    // implement other status notifications in the same way
}
```